# IIS hosted faulted workflow services

Tags: iis, workflow-foundation-4

I'm hosting my workflow services in IIS and I need to perform some custom actions when an instance is faulted for an internal exception during its excecution.

I found the WorkflowUnhandledExceptionBehavior extension, but there I can only use predefined actions. I would like to be able to have some "event" I can subscribe to to be able to run my own logic.
I think I should use a custom behavior, but where could I found a good example?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends a bit on what you want/need to do. If you add a [TrackingParticipant](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee513993.aspx) it can receive information about unhandled errors through a [WorkflowInstanceUnhandledExceptionRecord](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activities.tracking.workflowinstanceunhandledexceptionrecord.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

If any exception occurs inside any activity, it can be easily catch through inbuilt try catch activity. Put a try catch at the workflow level. If any exception generated, catch them and perform your own tasks.